# Hide all strings from a span matching criteria using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to hide all `$0.00` strings from a page and tried but did not succeeded. I get error: `TypeError: hidepricenull.each is not a function`. I am using it in wordpress.

HTML

```
<span class="amount">£200.00</span>
<span class="amount">£200.00</span>
```

Jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 var hidepricenull = $('span.amount').text();
     hidepricenull.each(function()   {
     if(hidepricenull == '£200.00') {
       $(this).hide(); 
     }
    });
});
```

Expected Output:

Hide the 2 text from spans

```
<span class="amount"></span>
<span class="amount"></span>
```

Comment: Because you need to create a collection for the `$.each();`

Comment: `hidepricenull` is a string, not a collection.

Comment: Added a `filter` version below, which should be slightly more efficient :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `hidepricenull` value is a string (the first item's text value, because of calling `text()`) but you need the collection and access the text per item:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var hidepricenull = $('span.amount');
    hidepricenull.each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == '£200.00') {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Note you could also start using the rather handy scoping DOM-ready shortcut for jQuery:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var hidepricenull = $('span.amount');
    hidepricenull.each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == '£200.00') {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Note the temp variable is no longer required and you can use a filter instead:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('span.amount').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() == '£200.00';
    }).hide();
});
```

Update to support multiple values:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('span.amount').filter(function () {
        var text = $(this).text();
        return text == '£200.00' || text == '£100.00';
    }).hide();
});
```

Update to support numeric comparisons (faster than strings for many values):

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('span.amount').filter(function () {
        var value = parseFloat($(this).text().substring(1));
        return value == 200 || value == 100 || value == 50;
    }).hide();
});
```

Comment: Just shorter... The speed difference is negligible.

Comment: and if I want to hide besides £200.00 also £100.00, on 3rd one won't be possible to add 2 returns.

Comment: ahaaa, I see now, so the best performance ones let's say for 10.000 elements which one do you think it is?

Comment: @user3467855: Example updated to convert the string to a numeric value and do match checks like `< 200` etc. Numeric matches will be faster (for many values).

Answer (score 3):

You should iterate over the items and check for it's text, you could try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var hidepricenull = $('span.amount');
    hidepricenull.each(function(){
        if($(this).text() == '£200.00') {
            $(this).hide(); 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var hidepricenull = $('span.amount');
hidepricenull.each(function()   {
    if($(this).text() == '£200.00') {
       $(this).hide(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: What kept you? (3 identical answers now) :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see previous answers before posting.. It's within the span of a minute.

Answer (score 0):

by using jquery u can do it simply

```
$('span:contains("£0.00")').hide();
```